# Чи має слово "ватажок" відповідник-фемінітив?

Tags: фемінітиви, рід

У новинах на [УНІАН](https://www.unian.ua/incidents/1877161-vatajok-grupi-pidlitkiv-z-chernigova-poprosila-vibachennya-u-pobitoji-shkolyarki-video.html) промайнув такий заголовок:

> "Ватажок" групи підлітків з Чернігова попросила вибачення у побитої школярки

З дієслова *попросила* зрозуміло, що "ватажком" є дівчина. Мене цікавить, чи є якийсь інший термін із схожим значенням, який би вживався на позначення осіб жіночої статі у подібному контексті.

Варіанти *голова* та *очільниця* зазвичай вживаються у більш формальному контексті:

> *[Голова](http://newsua.one/novosti/golova-nbu-rozpovila-pro-szo-itimetsya-u-memorandumi-z-mvf.html) НБУ розповіла, про що йтиметься у меморандумі з МВФ*
>
> *[Очільниця](http://www.dw.com/uk/%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8F-%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D1%83-%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%97-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BC-%D1%89%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%96/a-37917156) уряду Шотландії хоче новий референдум щодо незалежності*

Comment: Є слова [приві́дця](http://sum.in.ua/s/pryvidcja) і [прові́дця](http://sum.in.ua/s/providcja), але вони, як не дивно, чоловічого роду (просто перша відміна до слів «привідець» і «провідець», а не жіночий рід).

Answer (score 8):

«Словник української мови» в 11 томах:

> **[ПРОВОДИ́РКА](http://sum.in.ua/s/provodyrka)**, и, *ж.* Жіночий рід до **проводир**.
>
> ---
>
> **[ПРОВОДИ́Р](http://sum.in.ua/s/provodyr)**, я, *рідко* **ПРОВОДАР**, проводаря, *ч.*
>
> <…>
>
> 2. Те саме, що **ватажок** 1. <…>
> 3. *перен.* Передова людина свого часу, яка користується авторитетом і має вплив на інших; керівник. <…> //  Авангард (у 2 знач.). <…>
> 4. Те саме, що **ватажок** 3. <…>

Answer (score 7):

**Вожачка** (жін. рід до слова вожак).

Приклади:

- «Напевно, піонерська вожачка також вирішила показати себе, і то їй вдалося сповна». *Зірка Мензатюк* Як я руйнувала імперію. с. [54](//books.google.com/books?id=TwlWCgAAQBAJ&dq=%22%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0%22&pg=PA54).
- «…вівці, яким стали докучати мухи, попригинавши голови, побігли додому, надто їхня вожачка з чубчиком на лобі…». *Іван Гнатюк* Стежки-дороги. с. [118](//books.google.com/books?id=qf0XAQAAIAAJ&dq=%22%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0%22).

До речі, слово *вожак* походить від *вести*, яке має давнє, індоєвропейське походження. ЕСУМ, том 1, с. 363, 364.

Answer (score 5):

*Отаманша* [дівочої, підліткової, дитячої тощо ватаги].

> *Штаб повстанців очолив батько братів-отаманів Тимофій, якому на той час виповнилося 67 років. Його найменша дочка, гімназистка Олександра (майбутня отаманша Маруся) виконувала роль зв’язкової.* — Коваль Р. [«Життя і смерть отамана Соколовського»](http://www.ukrlife.org/main/evshan/zhnyva76.htm)
>
> *Отаманша організовувала наскоки на проїжджих московських купців.* —  Шевченко Г. [«Розбійниця з великої дороги»](https://history.sumynews.com/research/article/8887-sumska-rozbiinytsia.html)

Comment: Дякую за ваш варіант! Чи могли покращити свою відповідь, вказавши якесь джерело, де б був приклад вживання цього слова?

Comment: Чи не буде воно інтерпретовано як «дружина отамана»? Чи воно має обидва значення?

Comment: Та буде, хай йому абищо. Це якраз одна з найбільших відомих мені проблем сучасного українського фем-творення та вжитку - смислове співпадіння новотвору-фемінітиву зі старішим позначенням "дружина чи донька такого-то". І якщо для цієї конкретної новини, яка винесена на приклад, можна викрутитися тим, що дівчина ще явно не досягла шлюбного віку, то як дати раду у менш визначених ситуаціях - бігме, не знаю. Мені більше хотілося показати контраст "отаманші" (саме у значенні "лідерка стійкої підлітково-молодіжної групи, схильної до правопорушень чи асоціальних вчинків") до "голови" чи "очільниці".

Answer (score 2):

<sup>Оскільки тут згадують подібні слова, то теж приєднаюся.</sup>

Непитоме, але [широке](https://www.google.com.ua/search?lr=-lang_ru&safe=off&q="%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0") і затверджене слово **лідерка**.

> **[Лі́дерка](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=199360)**, **и**, ж. Жін. до [лі́дер](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=47771). *На тлі думок О. Теліги варто згадати, що тодішня лідерка українського жіночого руху Мілена Рудницька заперечувала “фашистівське і гітлерівське розуміння жінки” як домашньої істоти* (з наук. літ.); *Лідерка білоруських есерів навчалася в київському виші* (із журн.); *Після низки терактів у Парижі лідерка правих популістів з партії “Національний фронт” Марін Ле Пен заявила: “Ми мусимо контролювати наші кордони. Ми мусимо негайно призупинити міграцію й скасувати Шенгенський режим”* (з газ.).

Також инші похідні від *пр?від*.

> **[Провідниця](http://services.ulif.org.ua/grinch/Entry/index?wordid=44770)**, **-ці**, *ж*. Проводница, руководительница. *Ой дай мені провідничка — рідного братіка, ой дай мені провідницю, — хоть сестрицю* Мил. Св. 54.
>
> ---
>
> **[Привідниця](http://services.ulif.org.ua/grinch/Entry/index?wordid=43265)**, **-ці**, *ж*. Предводительница; руководительница.

Comment: Ого, ще один інтерфейс для словника Грінченка (можливо, не найкращий — враховуючи, що в них «?» іноді вилазить; хоча важко судити, не маючи всієї статистики помилок; на hrinchenko.com я часто бачив пропущені наголоси; в Грінченко на r2u поки що помилок не бачив, але не тому, що немає, а тому, що рідше користувався).